# How to convert a string like '20/11/2012 7:05:14 PM' to a TDateTime?

Tags: delphi

`SysUtils.StrToDate('20/11/2012 7:05:14 PM')` throws an excpetion. How do I get a `TDateTime` from that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid this kind of issues you must use the [`StrToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDateTime) method passing a [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) value with the settings of the format of the string to convert.

```
var
  AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
  LDateTime : TDateTime;
begin
   AFormatSettings:=TFormatSettings.Create;
   AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
   AFormatSettings.DateSeparator:='/';
   LDateTime:=  StrToDateTime('20/11/2012 7:05:14 PM', AFormatSettings);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to parse both a date and time, you should probably be using the [`SysUtils.StrToDateTime`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_StrToDateTime@string.html) method instead.

Otherwise, if you remove the time from the string it should work and give you just the date.